# Is writing over a not deinitialized object undefined behavior?

Tags: pointers, memory, rust, reference, undefined-behavior

```rust
struct C { ... }
impl C {
  pub fn new() { ... }
}
fn main() {
  let mut x = C::new();
  unsafe { *(&x as *mut C) = C::new(); } // We are overwriting an object without disposing old value.
}
```

Is it undefined behavior?

If it is, how should I dispose the old object (`x`) before the unsafe assignment?

Comment: Why not simply do `x = C::new()`?

Comment: I ask because the code as shown does invoke undefined behavior, but not for the reasons you imply. On the contrary, using `=`, the left hand side *must* be initialized.

Comment: @kmdreko Not simply `x = C::new()`, because I am learning to work with raw pointers.

Comment: @kmdreko I see: it had undefined behavior, because `x` was not `mut`. I've corrected that error.

Comment: `casting &C as *mut C` is still invalid, and the compiler will tell you so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not undefined bevaviour

```rust
struct C;
impl C {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        C
    }
}

impl Drop for C {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("C is Drop!");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = C::new();
    println!("before reassignment !");
    unsafe {
        *(&mut x as *mut C) = C::new();
    } // We are overwriting an object without disposing old value.
    println!("after reassignment !");
}
```

will print:

```
before reassignment !
C is Drop!
after reassignment !
C is Drop!
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not undefined behaviour (UB), the worst that could happen is leaking some resources that a `C::drop` would free. So even if you wrote directly to the pointer using [`ptr::write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.write.html) that wouldn't be UB because leaking resources [isn't considered UB](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html)
So this would be fine too:

```rust
struct C(i32);
impl C {
    pub fn new(x: i32) -> Self {
        C(x)
    }
}

impl Drop for C {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("C({}) is Drop!", self.0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = C::new(1);
    println!("before reassignment!");
    unsafe {
        (&mut x as *mut C).write(C::new(2));
    } // We are overwriting an object without disposing old value.
    println!("after reassignment!");
}
```

even if it outputs:

```
before reassignment !
after reassignment !
C(2) is Drop!
```

which shows that the initial `C` is never dropped, but as explained above that's simply not UB, even though usually it's undesired.